# What's difference between different ways to get GET parameter in Controller-Action in Zend framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I found several ways to get `GET` parameters inside **Controller > Action in Zend Framework 2**:

```
 $this->params()->fromRoute('id');

 $this->params('id');

 $this->getRequest()->getQuery()->get('id');
```

Is there any difference among these ways?

I guess, `params('id')` may give values from `GET` and `POST` both.
**fromRoute** and **getQuery** will give value from `GET` only, but `fromRoute` may give some advantages like sanitation or something?

Comment: [Zf2 Params Plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-params)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->params()->fromRoute('id');
```

This uses the [params plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-params) and returns a single named route parameter. This is used for parameters in segment routes (e.g. 'slug' from `/blog/:slug` or 'year' from `/archive/:year/:month/:day`).

```
$this->params('id');
```

This is just shorthand for `$this->params()->fromRoute('id');`.

```
$this->getRequest()->getQuery()->get('id');
```

This grabs a value from the query string.

Comment: The `params-helper` offers [more](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-params).

Comment: Thanks @Tim and @ copynpaste.
Does that mean, params() or params()->fromRoute('id') give the same result and can give value in both formats of URL?: delete/:id and delete?id=7

Comment: Sorry, my answer was a little inaccurate - I've edited it. `fromRoute()` only returns named segments from routes. It doesn't return query string parameters. This differs from how the equivalent function worked in ZF1.

Comment: @CoolZeroInfinity I thought so but it doesn't look like - [Github Code](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/master/src/Controller/Plugin/Params.php#L29)